# pandas insert and append into a new dataframe in a loop

Tags: pandas, dataframe, spacy-3

i would like to insert the output from a NER engine to dataframe as below

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |

i read a dataframe as above to get ID and then use that to read from a path , i have tried to create a dfindex variable to be used as loc in dataframe but it keeps overwritting

```
dfner = pd.DataFrame()
dfindex = 0
for index, row in dfl.iterrows():
    id = row['id']
    
    path = "C:\\Users\\myfolder\\"+str(row['chart'])+".txt"
    with open(path,"r") as myfile:
       target_string = myfile.read()
       print(id)
       #here i do the NER
       doc = nlp(target_string)
       for ent in doc.ents:
           print(ent.text,ent.label_)
           dfner.loc[dfindex,'id'] = str(id)
           dfner.[dfindex,'match'] = ent.label_
           dfindex+=1
```

output :

1

john name

doe  name

2

chris name

clark name

i would like to store this to a dataframe as below

| id | match |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | john |
| 1 | doe |
| 2 | chris |
| 2 | clark |

Comment: Can you provide the content of `dfl`?

Comment: added but i need the results in a new DF

Comment: I would suggest writing a function that does the import of one data set. Then `map` across all the file names and `reduce` using `pd.concat`

Answer (score 0):

I may have figured it out. I have used a empty list to count the number of entries and below is the code

```py
dfner.loc[len(listname)-1, 'match'] = ent.label_
dfner.loc[len(listname)-1, 'id'] = str(id)
```